# Tablesorter sorting issue when using date format with intitalsortorder

Tags: jquery, date, tablesorter

I am trying to sort the column of table that contains date in dd-mm-yyyy format. I am also trying to set the initialsortorder but it is generating numeric sort rather than date sort. There seems to be a issue when using `headers` along with `initialsortorder` in jquery **tablesorter** plugin.

I had tried the following:

```
$('#table').tablesorter({
     sortList: [[0,1]],
     dateFormat : "dd-mm-yyyy",
     headers: {   
              0: { sorter: 'shortDate' } 
            }
        });
```

The above code sorts initially but only in numeric format.

Another try:

```
 $('#table').tablesorter({
         //sortList: [[0,1]],
         dateFormat : "dd-mm-yyyy",
         headers: {   
                  0: { sorter: 'shortDate',sortInitialOrder: 'desc'} 
                }
            });
```

This one sorts according to date format specified but not sorting initially,
it sorts only when the header(thead) is clicked.

**Question:** How to generate initial sort with date format included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the original tablesorter (v2.0.5)

- The `sortInitialOrder` can not be set within the `headers` option. It is a global option only.
- `dateFormat` only accepts these options:

  - `"us"` - supports "mm-dd-yyyy" or "mm/dd/yyyy"
  - `"uk"`, `"dd/mm/yy"` or `"dd-mm-yy"` - supports "dd-mm-yyyy" or "dd/mm/yyyy"

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1447/) using the following code:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    dateFormat: 'uk',
    sortInitialOrder: 'desc',
    headers: {
        0: { sorter: 'shortDate' }
    }
});
```

Comment: What can i do to sort my dates that also consists time alogn with it